# Rally toolKit for Java how do i create and then attach a TestCaseResult to a TestCase

Tags: java, rally, testcase

general code where `testCase` is a `JsonObject`:

```
JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
result.addProperty("Verdict", "True");
result.addProperty("TestCase", Ref.getRelativeRef(testCase.get("_ref").getAsString()));

CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("TestCaseResult", result);
CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
```

I guess the two main questions I have are:

1. Am I creating the testCaseResult correctly?(with the testCase property being a reference to a testCase)
2. Do I need to attach my testCaseResult to my testCase? (`testCase.addProperty("Results", "testCaseResults reference"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Kyle! By way of example, here's a quick snippet that illustrates querying for a Test Case and then adding a new Test Case Result to it:

```
    // Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
    RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), 
            "user@company.com", "password");
    restApi.setWsapiVersion("1.34");
    restApi.setApplicationName("RestExample_AddTagsToTestCase");        

    //Query User
    QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
    userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName"));
    userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "user@company.com"));
    QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
    JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
    JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
    JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
    String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").toString();

    // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
    QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
    testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
    testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC4"));
    QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
    JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").toString();

    try {

        //Add a Test Case Result                
        System.out.println("Creating Test Case Result...");
        JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Date", "2012-06-12T18:00:00.000Z");
        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Automated Selenium Test Runs");
        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2012.05.31.0020101");
        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", userRef);
        newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", testCaseRef);

        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
        CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);            

        if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {

            System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));          

            //Read Test Case
            String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
            System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", ref));
            GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
            getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
            GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
            JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
            System.out.println(String.format("Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s",
                    obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString()));                 
        } else {
            String[] createErrors;
            createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
            System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
            for (int i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
            }
        }

    } finally {
        //Release all resources
        restApi.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the ref of the test case that the new test case result is associated with is the correct way to do this.  Once the create operation succeeds querying the testcase again should include the newly created test case result in its results collection.