# Rally Rest API code unable to create new Test Case Results added

Tags: api, rally

I've recently created a java project with the associated RallyRestToolkit jar files. The intent for my code is to create a new TestCaseResult to the specified Test Case. The code currently works in Eclipse without any errors. However when I go to view the result in the UI of Rally I don't see it added. Am I missing something in my code?

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.DeleteRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.DeleteResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URI;

//import rally.TestCaseResult;

//import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class RallyUpdater {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        //Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),"user@company.com", "password");
        restApi.setWsapiVersion("1.38");
        restApi.setApplicationName("Add Test Case Result");

            // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
            QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
            testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Rally REST API Enhancment Object ID to Formatted ID"));
            testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC7020"));
            QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
            JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
            //Add a Test Case Result
            System.out.println("Creating TestCase Result...");
            JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
            //newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Test Case Result");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Test");

            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2012.05.31.0020101");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", "Sam Adams");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", "/testcase/14321026920");
            System.out.println("added tester");
            //newTestCaseResult.addProperty("FormattedID", "TC7020");

            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
            System.out.println("Done");
            System.out.println(String.format( "Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));

            restApi.close();
    }
}
```

NEW CODE:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.DeleteRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.DeleteResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URI;



public class RallyUpdater {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        //Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),"username@company.com", "password");
        restApi.setWsapiVersion("1.36");
        restApi.setApplicationName("Add Test Case Result");

            // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
            QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
            testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Rally REST API Enhancment Object ID to Formatted ID"));
            testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC7xxx"));
            QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
            JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();`
            //Add a Test Case Result
            System.out.println("Creating TestCase Result...");
            JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Test");

            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2012.05.31.0020101");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", "Joe Smith");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", "/testcase/14321026920");
            System.out.println("added tester");
            //newTestCaseResult.addProperty("FormattedID", "TC7xxx");

            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
            System.out.println("Done");
            System.out.println(String.format( "Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));

            restApi.close();
    }
}
```

New Code 03-11-14

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.DeleteRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.DeleteResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URI;

public class RallyNewTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


     RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),"jsmith@company.com", "password");
     restApi.setWsapiVersion("1.38");
     restApi.setApplicationName("Add Test Case Result");

     QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
     userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "Joe Smith"));
     userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "jsmith@company.com"));
     QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
     JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
     JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
     JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
     String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").toString();

     if (userQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
         System.out.println("User Found"); 
     } else {
         System.out.println("User not found");
     }
     System.out.println("Creating a test case result...");

     QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
     testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Rally REST API Enhancment Object ID to Formatted ID"));
     testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TCxxx"));
     QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
     JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
     String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();
     if (testCaseQueryResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
         System.out.println("Test Case Found"); 
     } else {
         System.out.println("Test Case not found");
     }


     try {
            //Add a Test Case Result
             System.out.println("Creating TestCase Result...");
             JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
             newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
             newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Test");
             newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2012.05.31.0020101");
             newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", "Joe Smith");
             newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", "/testcae/17080774372");
             System.out.println("added testcase info");

             CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("newtestcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
             CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);  

             if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                 System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));          

                 //Read Test Case
                 String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                 System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", ref));
                 GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
                 getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
                 GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
                 JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
                 System.out.println(String.format("Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s",
                         obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString())); 

             } else {
                 String[] createErrors;
                 createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                 System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
                 for (int i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
                     System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
                System.out.println(createErrors[j]);                 
             }
         }
             }finally {
         //Release all resources
         restApi.close();
     }   

 } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, i'll try it shortly. What number goes in the "..../testcase/12345678910" portion? Is it the object Id or the Formatted ID? Just want to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what is missing is the needed association of the TestCaseResult to a TestCase:

`newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", "/testcase/12345678910");`

This answer:

[Rally toolKit for Java how do i create and then attach a TestCaseResult to a TestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987076/rally-toolkit-for-java-how-do-i-create-and-then-attach-a-testcaseresult-to-a-tes)

Provides an example of how to accomplish the creation of a TCR associated to an existing TestCase.

Comment: I figured out the naming convention above(with the URL code). However I added that portion of code in and the same result occurred. Any other idea's to try? Appreciate the help – user2697781 just now  edit

Comment: Are there warnings or errors on the create response? How are you obtaining the TestCase object id?

Comment: No warnings are visible on the console. It just goes through the code and displays the System.out.println messages I have in the code. Any additional tool suggestions outside of Eclipe to run my code through would be appreciated (so I can provide you).

Comment: Also to the second Question. I dont currently have the object ID. Just the Formatted ID from the UI and the Ref # from the URL. Does the object ID need to go in the code?

Comment: Thanks Mark, the updated code is appended below the old code. I have since added the restApi.create() call as you instructed. There is an actual java.lang.NullPointerException error occurring now on the line "System.out.println(String.format( "Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));". Any idea's? Getting closer. thx

Comment: full error reads Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at RallyUpdater.main(RallyUpdater.java:58)

Comment: The nullPointerException is occurring because the object did not get created successfully and getObject is returning null. Please look again at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987076/rally-toolkit-for-java-how-do-i-create-and-then-attach-a-testcaseresult-to-a-tes and review the if/else block on wasSuccessful which traps for this condition, and only does getObject() if the create succeeded. If it doesn't, it loops through the errors collection, and tells us why it didn't succeed. What happens if you run the example in the prior answer, unaltered?

Comment: Thanks Mark. I have created a new project and created a new class with the code specified on your link. I've updated the applicable fields with my applicable information. However I'm having difficulty getting the code to work due to multiple Syntax error's. I've attached my new code above. I've specified the rows of code (with an arrorw '----->') that are having the Syntax errors. I'm not sure why these errors are occurring or quite how to resolve them. Any help you can provide on these Syntax errors would be appreciated.

Comment: Mark, I've taken another stab at using the code referenced on stackoverflow.com/questions/10987076/… and the Syntax errors have dissapeared. I've also updated the code above. The Test Case result is still failing to be created with no errors. However the Error log is displaying the error in the Eclipse Console as designed. The Error says "Requested type name "newtestcaseresult" is unknown." Any ideas?